# Can I differientiate between two processes with the same name?

Tags: linux, process

I sometimes run JDev and SQLDev at the same time; then, one of them would freeze. I run top, and both of them appear as COMMAND java. I use their PID to differienciate them, the lower one is (I believe) the older one, so I just have to remember wich one I ran first so I know which is which and I can kill the correct one. Is there, tho, a better solution since there might be more than 2 processes named java, and often times I've killed the wrong one?

Comment: You would also have to worry about PID reuse, so relying on sequential PID allocation won't work all the time.  Some Unices also have random PID allocation.

Comment: `ps x` seems to show arguments, so you could use that to tell one `java` from another.